# Compilation error: Smart cast to '<type>' is impossible, because '<variable>' is a local variable that is captured by a changing closure

Tags: kotlin, casting

To simplify my real use case, let's suppose that I want to find the maximum number in a list:

```
var max : Int? = null
listOf(1, 2, 3).forEach {
    if (max == null || it > max) {
        max = it
    }
}
```

However, compilation fails with the following error:

> Smart cast to 'Int' is impossible, because 'max' is a local variable that is captured by a changing closure

Why does a changing closure prevent smart cast from working in this example?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In general, when a mutable variable is captured in a lambda function closure, smart casts are not applicable to that variable, both inside the lambda and in the declaring scope after the lambda was created.

It's because the function may escape from its enclosing scope and may be executed later in a different context, possibly multiple times and possibly in parallel.  As an example, consider a hypothetical function `List.forEachInParallel { ... }`, which executes the given lambda function for each element of the list, but in parallel.

The compiler must generate code that will remain correct even in that severe case, so it doesn't make an assumption that the value of variable remains unchanged after the null check and thus cannot smart cast it.

However, `List.forEach` is quite different, because it is an [`inline`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html) function. The body of an inline function and the bodies of its functional parameters (unless the parameter has `noinline` or `crossinline` modifiers) are inlined at the call site, so the compiler could reason about the code in a lambda passed as an argument to inline function as if it was written directly in the calling method body making the smart cast possible.

It could, but currently, it doesn't. Simply because that feature is not implemented yet. There is an open issue for it: [KT-7186](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7186).

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to [Ilya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869184/ilya) for the detailed explanation of the problem!
You can use the standard `for(item in list){...}` expression like this:

```
var max : Int? = null
val list = listOf(1, 2, 3)
for(item in list){
    if (max == null || item > max) {
        max = item
    }
}
```

Comment: This saved my day, bummer I cannot upvote twice!  And it should really not be called a workaround IMHO, as it implies that "for(item in list) {...}" is some sort of anti-pattern which it is not in my eyes. (Yes, I'm somewhat old school when it comes to coding.)

Comment: Very elegant and clean solution. Requires minimum changes from original code and doesn't add extra garbage (literally and metaphorically). Well done!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `foreach` creates multiple closures, each of which access the same `max` which is a `var`.

What should happen if `max` were set to `null` in another of the closures after the `max == null` check but before `it > max`?

Since each closure can theoretically work independently (potentially on multiple threads) but all access the same `max`, you can't guarantee it won't change during execution.

Comment: Shouldn't the body of `forEach` be inlined? In that case, `max` should be just a local variable, thus mutli-threading is not an issue.

Comment: Multi-threading will still be an issue if the body of `forEach` makes threads. Inlining the creation of a thread doesn't inline the thread.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a compiler bug to me.

If the inline lambda parameter in `forEach` were marked as `crossinline` then I would expect a compilation error because of the possibility of concurrent invocations of the lambda expression.

Consider the following `forEach` implementation:

```
inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEach(crossinline action: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    val executorService: ExecutorService = ForkJoinPool.commonPool()
    val futures = map { element -> executorService.submit { action(element) } }
    futures.forEach { future -> future.get() }
}
```

The above implementation would fail to compile without `crossinline` modifier. Without it, the lambda may contain [non-local returns](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#non-local-returns) which means it cannot be used in a concurrent fashion.

I suggest creating an issue: [Kotlin (KT) | YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT).

Comment: Exactly, that's what confused me in the first place. If a lambda body is completely inlined, then I would expect to be able to do everything I would do if I were to write the inlined code manually.

Answer (score 1):

As this is in the top results for the error `Smart cast to '<type>' is impossible, because '<variable>' is a local variable that is captured by a changing closure` here is a general solution that worked for me (even if the closure is not inlined):

Sample showing this error:

```kotlin
var lastLine: String? = null
File("filename").useLines {
    lastLine = it.toList().last()
}

if(lastLine != null) {
    println(lastLine.length) // error! lastLine is captured by the useLines closure above
}
```

Fix: Create a new variable that is not captured by the closure:

```kotlin
var lastLine: String? = null
File("filename").useLines {
    lastLine = it.toList().last()
}

val finalLastLine = lastLine
if(finalLastLine != null) {
    println(finalLastLine.length)
}
```

Comment: Technically this works, but shouldn't be done in practice, especially in loops. This will create a lot of garbage and isn't as scalable compared to Ivo Stoyanov's implementation. This is a good 'hack' for personal projects, but not recommended in commercial applications.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your use-case the elvis-operator may also help:

```
var max: Int? = null
listOf(1, 2, 3).forEach {
        if (max == null || it > max ?: Int.MIN_VALUE) {
            max = it
        }
    }
```

The first condition (max == null) is only nececesary if the list may really contain Int.MIN_VALUE as first entry.