# Smart cast to 'Bitmap!' is impossible, because 'textBitmap' is a local variable that is captured by a changing closure

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

when ever I build my project I got this error

here is the kotlin class code

```
var textBitmap: Bitmap? = null
dynamicItem.dynamicText[imageKey]?.let { drawingText ->
            dynamicItem.dynamicTextPaint[imageKey]?.let { drawingTextPaint ->
drawTextCache[imageKey]?.let {
                    textBitmap = it
                } ?: kotlin.run {
                    textBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawingBitmap.width, drawingBitmap.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
                    val drawRect = Rect(0, 0, drawingBitmap.width, drawingBitmap.height)
                    val textCanvas = Canvas(textBitmap)
                    drawingTextPaint.isAntiAlias = true
                    val fontMetrics = drawingTextPaint.getFontMetrics();
                    val top = fontMetrics.top
                    val bottom = fontMetrics.bottom
                    val baseLineY = drawRect.centerY() - top / 2 - bottom / 2
                    textCanvas.drawText(drawingText, drawRect.centerX().toFloat(), baseLineY, drawingTextPaint);
                    drawTextCache.put(imageKey, textBitmap as Bitmap)
                }
```

I couldn't figure out how to fix it

Comment: you can just define one more variable within `run` lambda  . `val textBitmap2 = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawingBitmap.width, drawingBitmap.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); textBitmap = textBitmap2;  drawTextCache.put(imageKey, textBitmap2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically Kotlin can't smart cast `textBitmap` to a non-null `Bitmap` inside that lambda. You're probably getting the error on the `Canvas(textBitmap)` call, which can't take a null parameter, and the compiler can't guarantee `textBitmap` isn't null at that moment.

It's a limitation of lambdas referencing external `var`s which can be changed - I think it's because a lambda could potentially be run at some other time, so no guarantees can be made about what's happening to that external variable and whether something else could have modified it. I don't know the details, there's some chat [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38927809/13598222) if you like.

The fix is pretty easy though, if all you're doing is creating a `textBitmap` variable and assigning something to it:

```
// Assign it as a result of the expression - no need to create a var first and keep
// changing the value, no need for a temporary null value, it can just be a val
val textBitmap: Bitmap? =
    dynamicItem.dynamicText[imageKey]?.let { drawingText ->
        dynamicItem.dynamicTextPaint[imageKey]?.let { drawingTextPaint ->
            drawTextCache[imageKey]
            ?: Bitmap.createBitmap(drawingBitmap.width, drawingBitmap.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).apply {
                    val drawRect = Rect(0, 0, drawingBitmap.width, drawingBitmap.height)
                    val textCanvas = Canvas(this)
                    drawingTextPaint.isAntiAlias = true
                    val fontMetrics = drawingTextPaint.getFontMetrics();
                    val top = fontMetrics.top
                    val bottom = fontMetrics.bottom
                    val baseLineY = drawRect.centerY() - top / 2 - bottom / 2
                    textCanvas.drawText(drawingText, drawRect.centerX().toFloat(), baseLineY, drawingTextPaint);
                    drawTextCache.put(imageKey, this)
            }
        }
    }
```

I'd recommend breaking the bitmap creation part out into its own function for readability, and personally I'd avoid the nested `let`s (because it's not immediately obvious what you get in what situation) but that's a style choice

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing nested `let` like that, i would prefer to do some guard clause

```kotlin
val drawingText = dynamicItem.dynamicText[imageKey] ?: return // or you could assign an empty string `?: "" `
val drawingTextPaint = dynamicItem.dynamicTextPaint[imageKey] ?: return
val textBitmap: Bitmap = drawTextCache[imageKey] ?: Bitmap.createBitmap(drawingBitmap.width, drawingBitmap.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).applyCanvas {
   val drawRect = Rect(0, 0, drawingBitmap.width, drawingBitmap.height)
   val fontMetrics = drawingTextPaint.getFontMetrics()
   val top = fontMetrics.top
   val bottom = fontMetrics.bottom
   val baseLineY = drawRect.centerY() - top / 2 - bottom / 2
   drawingTextPaint.isAntiAlias = true
   drawText(drawingText, drawRect.centerX().toFloat(), baseLineY, drawingTextPaint);
}
drawTextCache.put(imageKey, textBitmap)
```

Comment: Yeah I'd go this way - or do `val textBitmap = run { }` with everything inside, and evaluate to null where appropriate (null ``drawingText`` etc), if you need to set `textBitmap` to something and you can't just exit the containing function. I just feel like it's a lot easier to follow like this